# Create API for exist Rail project and make authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, react-native

I have working Rails project which is now just like simple web-site. I need to create API to connect it with React Native mobile app. All tutorials describe only how to create Rails API from scratch, but not how to integrate it on exist web project. So i confused how to realize it. Should i just add into my exist controllers something like:

```
respond_to :html, :json
```

in the end of the each action that i need also for API?
Or should i change actions to something like:

```
respond_to do |format|    
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @user }    
end
```

Or should i create new folder inside "Controllers" folder and call it "api" and create new controllers only for AP?
Also should i do any additional changes to my Rails application besides changes inside controllers?

**Updates:**

Well, after some investigation i understand that perhaps the best way is to create inside controllers folder new folder and inside that folder store all api versions like v1, v2 etc. Controller files inside /api/v1 should have such code for example:

```
class API::V1::PropertiesController < Application controller
 respond_to json
 def index
  properties = Properties.all 
 respond_with properties
 end
end
```

also in routes we should add namespaces:

```
namespace :api do
 namespace :v1 do
  resources :properties
 end
end
```

This will allow to get properties via endpoint /api/v1/properties.
Bigger problem is how to make authentication for exist project, if i already how authentication there done with Device. All tutorial describe this for api only projects. Not for real projects

Comment: You can create any endpoint which is gonna be available for any HTTP request using a "normal" controller which inherits from ApplicationController, you can use versioning, namespaces, inherit from ActionController::API, etc, just depending in your case.

Comment: @SebastianPalma you mean that each method that i wrote would work? What is best practice then?

Comment: I meant, every routed action in your controller will be available from outside your application, any HTTP request can "reach" them. In your case, just create a couple of namespaces, e.g: Api::V1 and there the controllers you need.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you should create seprate controller with namespace API and place api only controller in that , you can use json.builder for preparing response, if you think that codes in both the controllers [ webapp controller / api controller] then you should also use services which will minimize the effort of writing code again , as well you can manage your code in better manner by using services. you can choose which ever way you would like. good luck!